# Linking library syntax with gfortran

Tags: compilation, fortran, g++, gfortran, dynamic-linking

In C++, if I want to do a custom compile (meaning to link additional libraries), I usually do the following:

```
g++ filename -o outputname -I/include_libraries_here -L/link_libraries_here -rpath=path_for_dynamic_linking_here
```

How would I go about to do a similar thing using gfortran.  I tried:

```
gfortran filename -o outputname -I/include_libraries_here -L/link_libraries_here -rpath=path_for_dynamic_linking_here
```

So far, the syntax -I and -L work, suggesting that I managed to link and include the libraries.  However, it seems that gfortran does not recognize rpath as a valid command.

Please let me know and thank you.

Comment: Why does it seem? What happens?

Comment: The compiler said that rpath is not a valid command.  I also tried using just -R, still the same error.

Comment: and what about -Wl,rpath.... don't remember the details, I don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use rpath during linking. Of course, you can.

Take a look here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun() {
  printf("Hello from C\n");
}
```

we can create shared lib like this:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libfun.so fun.c
```

Then, we can compile following code:

```
program hello
  print *, "Hello World!"
  call fun()
end program hello
```

like this:

```
# without -rpath
gfortran -fno-underscoring -o hello -L. -lfun hello.f90
# in this case you have to make sure libfun.so is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# with rpath
gfortran -fno-underscoring -o hello -L. -Wl,-rpath=`pwd` -lfun hello.f90
# in this case, library will be properly located at runtime
```

This will allow calling function from shared lib

```
./hello
 Hello World!
Hello from C
```

-rpath is ld's argument

```
-rpath=dir
           Add a directory to the runtime library search path.  This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.  All -rpath arguments are concatenated
           and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.
```

Useful link:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html

Comment: I struggled a bit with this answer, because the order of the depending source and library files matters for the `gcc` linker. Hopefully you could reproduce this? Nevertheless I've added my observations as a new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

#### In addition to the accepted answer, please be aware of the following behavior of the `gcc` linker

As the `gcc` linker parses the command line only once from left to right, the order of the depending source and library files really matters. As `hello.f90` uses a function defined in `libfun`, it must be placed before the library.

Hence the linking shall be done like this:

```bash
# without -rpath
gfortran -fno-underscoring -o hello -L. hello.f90 -lfun 
# in this case you have to make sure libfun.so is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# with rpath
gfortran -fno-underscoring -o hello -L. -Wl,-rpath=`pwd` hello.f90 -lfun 
# in this case, library will be properly located at runtime
```

Tested with `gcc` version gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110.

More information regarding `gcc` linker invokation could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/9222996).

Comment: This seems more like a comment. The linker is actually `ld`, being called by any compiler, not GCC specific.

Comment: Best would be to update the accepted answer. I left a comment there, but I believe it should be done by the original author.